# Tipc module not found

Tags: sockets, tipc

I was going to execute TIPC programs on my ubuntu machine.I have downloaded tipcutils2.0.2
and executed all make file but when i try to run command

```
    tipc-config netid="" ,,,,,
```

It shows he following error

```
    ~/tipcutils-2.0.2/tipc-config$ ./tipc-config -netid=1234 -a=1.1.8 -be=eth:eth0
     TIPC module not installed
```

I have used modprobe as well as apt-get install commands  but cant install tipc module.Please suggest how to install this module....

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this problem is linux command 'modprobe' .It is used in following way:

```
    modprobe tipc
```

and tipc module is installed .
I have used it and my problem is resolved .

Comment: Thanks.  My TIPC socket create was failing. modprobe worked for me as well.